# Is there any syntax checker for knockout.js?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, knockout.js

I like knockout.js, the only problem is Visual Studio knows nothing about this framework, so it does not prevent me from silly things like assigning some value to observable property with '=' operator which makes it regular property, and it's not easy to reveal at compile time and often at runtime even. 
I wonder is there any syntax checker/highlighter for Visual Studio 2010 that helps me prevent faults like this? What about VS 2011? It might be a great help for developers who are new to knockout. Thanks

Comment: I don't know of any, but that would be problematic. The operation will work, without error, because it is a valid operation to reassign that observable to an int in javascript.

Comment: sure, it is valid, and I expect it to be no more than some kind of warning about possible misuse, taking into account it was declared as observable. More general question would be Is any technique to prevent faults like this for developers new to Knockout? Note it's pretty typical misuse and I'm afraid a lot of time will be lost because of faults like this

Answer (score 0):

In 2010 you can get IntelliSense for JavaScript libraries by referencing them using the following syntax at the top of the JS file.

```
/// <reference path="ScriptFile1.js" />
```

This link should provide more information: [JScript IntelliSense Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385682.aspx)

VS 2012 you don't even have to do this...